# Why these "union" of MDX queries do not work as expected?

Tags: ssis, union, mdx

I have these 2 MDX queries:

```
with member v1 as [measures].[val 1]
select {[measures].[val 1],[measures].[val 2] } on columns,
Filter(
     ([Factor].[Name].[ALL].Children-[Factor].[Name].[abc]
     ,[product].[product].[bike]), v1<>0
    )
on Rows
From [Cube]

with member v1 as [measures].[val 1]
select {[measures].[val 1],[measures].[val 2] } on columns,
Filter(
     ([Factor].[Name].[abc]
      ,[product].[product].[car]), v1<>0
     )
on Rows
From [Cube]
```

When I run them separately, both worked as expected.

If I "union" them like these:

```
with member v1 as [measures].[val 1]
select {[measures].[val 1],[measures].[val 2] } on columns,
{
   Filter(
          ([Factor].[Name].[ALL].Children-[Factor].[Name].[abc]
          ,[product].[product].[bike]), v1<>0
     )
,
   Filter(
          ([Factor].[Name].[abc]
          ,[product].[product].[car]), v1<>0
        )
}
on Rows
From [Cube]
```

The result set showed the correct number of rows but value of [measures].[val 1] is not expected.

Is this the right way to do "UNION" of 2 MDX queries?
If not, how to do it right?

Answer (score 1):

You look like you are using `union` correct.

If you rearrange the script slightly does it help?

```
with 
set [unionedset] AS
{
   Filter(
          ([Factor].[Name].[ALL].Children-[Factor].[Name].[abc]
          ,[product].[product].[bike])
          , [measures].[val 1]<>0
     )
,
   Filter(
          ([Factor].[Name].[abc]
          ,[product].[product].[car])
          ,[measures].[val 1]<>0
        )
}
select 
  {[measures].[val 1],[measures].[val 2] } on columns,
  [unionedset] on Rows
From [Cube]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with member v1 as sum(([Factor].[Name].currentmember,[product].[product].currentmember),[measures].[val 1])
select {[measures].[val 1],[measures].[val 2] } on columns,
{
   Filter(
          ([Factor].[Name].[ALL].Children-[Factor].[Name].[abc]
          ,[product].[product].[bike]), v1<>0
     )
,
   Filter(
          ([Factor].[Name].[abc]
          ,[product].[product].[car]), v1<>0
        )
}
on Rows
From [Cube]
```